# Androidの画面を暗くする処理について

Tags: android, java, android-studio, android-layout

Androidで画面を暗くするアプリを作りたいです。

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
            lp.screenBrightness = 0;
            getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        }
    });
}
```

上記のようにボタンを押すと画面が暗くなるようにしました。 
しかし、暗くなるのはウィンドウだけでアプリを閉じると適用されなくなってしまいます。 
lp.screenBrightness = 0;  (0.0（暗い）～1.0（明るい)) 
としていますが、SeekBarの数値に追随して画面を暗くし、0.0以下の暗さでかつ、ウィンドウを閉じた後も画面を暗くする処理を継続することは可能でしょうか。
そういった関数や処理があれば教えてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android.provider.Settings.System で、SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE を SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL にした上で、
SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS の値を変更すると変えられます。

Comment: SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL にすると0.0~1.0の範囲以上に暗くしたり、明るくしたりできるということでしょうか？

Comment: @g13 輝度の自動調整が働いたままだとSCREEN_BRIGHTNESSを変更しても無視されてしまいます。それを防ぎます。